# Why do all the other fields get erased when I try to update one field of the row?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, xampp, lamp

**Code:**

```
$data = $request>only(['shell_rec','intake','agency','conduit','coupler']);
CoachStatus::where('coach_id',$coach_id)->first()->update($data);
```

**Configuration in my local system:** LAMP Stack

**Configuration in my online server:** Windows XAMPP

**On my local system:**

When I give a request to Postman (`localhost:8000/status/update?coach_num=CHCER32&shell_rec=2018-05-09`), only the `shell_rec` field gets updated and other fields of that row remain as such.

**On the server:**

After hosting the code in an server, if I give requests (`http://website.com/status/update?coach_num=CHCER32&shell_rec=2018-05-09`), the `shell_rec` field of the row gets updated, whereas the other fields of the row like `intake`,`agency`,`conduit`,`coupler` gets erased.

Why is this happening after hosting? Is there a simple workaround to solve this as the code perfectly works on my local system, but not on the server?

Comment: You're calling on other fields as well that are not present in the request. `intake`, `agency`, `conduit`, and `coupler` are all likely being set to `null` in your `$data` array. Can you confirm with `dd($data)`?

Comment: @maiorano84 The `$data` array only has the `shell_rec` index on dumping. It doesn't have any other indices like `intake`, `agency`, `conduit`, `coupler`.

Comment: Please log the query and post the result: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); CoachStatus::where('coach_id',$coach_id)->first()->update($data); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @Benedict check differences in your installations (local vs online), cause this the place where you have inconsistencies. Are you sure that these match php versions, .ini configs? Personally I would check (as for online server) against some Linux stack, or build your own, cause you will certainly not run your production on Windows XAMPP...